# Query count for specific column from specific table JOIN other table have same column?

Tags: mysql, join

I can get count of `home_id` from `server_homes`, but when i make `NATURAL JOIN user_homes` (this table have same column `home_id` with same value)
the result from `count` is multiple (if real result is 2 the `count` is 4).

This code what i use:

```
        return $this->resultQuery('SELECT COUNT(home_id) AS total FROM `'.$this->table_prefix.'server_homes`

        '.($search_field ? '
        NATURAL JOIN `'.$this->table_prefix.'user_homes`
        NATURAL JOIN `'.$this->table_prefix.'remote_servers` 
        NATURAL JOIN `'.$this->table_prefix.'home_ip_ports`

        ' : '').'
        ');
```

Comment: Would a `count(distinct(home_id))` work?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @cwallenpoole YES, that's work!!, i was expend 2 days hhhhh LOL. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO the problem here is that the `home_id` is not unique among all of the tables. I'd presume there would be multiple home IP ports or multiple remote servers for the same house. This will mean that your total number of rows will be #server homes + #dupes user homes + #dupes remote servers + #dupes home IP ports.

The way to get around this is to make sure you are only counting the IDs once:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT( `home_id` ) ) FROM 
   -- Yada yada
```